# Why is my Hibernate Query returning stale data?

Tags: java, hibernate, wicket, ehcache, databinder

**Quick Version**

Basically, I'm updating a Hibernate Table and subsequent queries are loading a stale value.

**Detailed Version**

Hibernate (3.3.1.GA) and EhCache (2.4.2).

Persisted `Book` object with a `List<PageContent>` of pages and I'm adding a page to the middle of this book.  I'm using Databinder/Wicket, though I do not think that is related.

```
 public void createPageContent(Book book, int index) {
     Databinder.getHibernateSession().lock(book, LockMode.UPGRADE);
     PageContent page = new PageContent(book);
     book.addPage(page, index);
     CwmService.get().flushChanges(); // commits the transaction
 }
```

The applicable fields/method in `Book` are:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name="book_id")
@IndexColumn(name="pageNum")
@Cascade({CascadeType.ALL, CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN})
private List<PageContent> pages = new ArrayList<PageContent>();

public synchronized void addPage(PageContent page, int index) {
    pages.add(index, page);
}
```

The end result is that there is a new page added to a list and the database is updated accordingly and I've confirmed this in my datastore.  However, the next query for a page, say "Page #4," loads the "old" Page #4 instead of the new Page #4:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("book", book));
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("pageNum", pageNum));
criteria.setCacheable(true);
```

So, I grudgingly remove caching from the criteria.  It queries the datastore, but *still returns the wrong value*.  However, in both cases, if I wait about 2 minutes, everything is working as expected.  I presume caching is still involved.  Both `PageContent` and `Book` use this caching strategy:

```
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
```

I confess I'm new to caching and just set up this file for the first time.  Here's my ehcache.xml:

```
<defaultCache maxElementsInMemory="10000" eternal="false" timeToIdleSeconds="120" timeToLiveSeconds="120" overflowToDisk="true" diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="30" maxElementsOnDisk="10000000" diskPersistent="false" diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" statistics="false"/>

<!-- Hibernate's Cache for keeping 'lastUpdated' data on each table.  Should never expire. -->
<cache name="org.hibernate.cache.UpdateTimestampsCache" eternal="true" />

<!-- Hibernate's Query Cache - should probably be limited -->
<cache name="org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache" maxElementsInMemory="1000" />
```

**UPDATE**: Removing the `@Cache` annotations on my datastore objects removes the problem.  Of course, I would like to cache these objects because page modification is much less frequent than access.

So, thoughts?  There are several other issues related as well, including with deleting pages.  Everything updates the database as expected, but actual behavior is wonky.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE #2**:  Via debugging, I can confirm that the Datastore has the correct information and when the query runs, it falls back on the Second-Level Cache - which has dirty information.  I presume it's not up to me to evict from the cache every time the data changes?

Comment: when you run the criteria query, do you see the sql being run? (logger org.hibernate.sql)

Comment: Yes, my logging statements all support the comments I made above.  When I had the query cached, EhCache reported a 'hit' on the cache entry.  When I did `setCacheable(false)` the query does indeed run.

Comment: So the next thing is are you certain that the changes you are expecting to be in the database are definitely in the db and visible to another connection?

Comment: I can confirm that the database changes are made instantly - I'm looking directly at the table through the PostGreSQL GUI.  I'm also not using any sort of distributed database, so I presume this means any subsequent connections can access them.  I'm quite certain this is related to the cache since everything works fine 120 seconds later - which is my TTL for EHCache.  See Update.

Comment: My current intent is to leave the Java code alone and update Hibernate/EhCache.  I've already noticed one issue:  http://ehcache.org/documentation/hibernate.html#Configure_Ehcache_as_the_Second_Level_Cache_Provider  I was using the second method, but using Hibernate 3.3.

Comment: Updating and fixing all documented issues I could find did NOT solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the problem, but it introduces something else.

Basically, when modifying a `Book` object's `List<PageContent>` field, Hibernate does three things:

1. Expires the TimeStamp cache entry for both `Book` and `PageContent`
2. Does many queries to reset the `pageNum` field on each `PageContent` object
3. Removes the `Book` object from the Second Level Cache.

This ensures that subsequent queries will search for new objects, etc.  However:

1. Hibernate fails to remove each renumbered `PageContent` object from the Second Level Cache

As a result, any query for the list of pages will run properly, but then will fall back on stale Second Level Cache values for the actual data.

I presume this is because Hibernate feels a `pageNum` change is not a change in data but a change in behind-the-scenes management.  However, that is the data that I would like to read and display.

The solution is to manually refresh every page after the insertion/deletion has occurred.

Answer (score 0):

After `CwmService.get().flushChanges(); // commits the transaction` do an explicit commit.
`flush()` only flushes the changes to db but does not commit it. I am not sure about `flushChanges()` though.

Comment: CwmService.get().flushChanges() is my custom method.  It runs Hibernate's Transaction.commit() which, according to the JavaDoc, "Flush(es) the associated Session."

Comment: Are you using a separate transaction to write to db everytime? And after the transaction completes, are you able to see changes in db?